# Hive - Create new Table and insert updated data into it

Tags: hive, hiveql

is Hive allow us to select updated data and create new table?
Which means a new table will be created using the same schema of old table after some row of data is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTAS (Create Table As Select)

---

The basic syntax:

```
create table my_new_table
as
select  ... 
from    my_table
;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)

Comment: What do you mean by UPDATED? can you describe the whole scenario?

Comment: Erm.....lets say I selected some records into new table and update. Is that possible to include these 2 action into one query?

Or I update some record first, after that I insert them into new table

Comment: You don'y need to do any update, just to manipulate the data within the select of the CTAS statement

Comment: create table weather_test
as
SELECT * FROM
(UPDATE weather
SET sflag = 9
where obstime = 800)
;


Something like this?

Comment: No, something like `create table new_weather as SELECT case when obstime = 800 then 9 else sflag end as sflag  FROM weather;`

Comment: I think we almost there :). What if JOIN is involve? How should the query look like?

Comment: Any valid SELECT will do

Comment: CREATE TABLE new_test AS
SELECT DISTINCT va.stationid
FROM flight f 
    JOIN airport a 
        ON (f.Origin = a.IATA)  
    JOIN vw_airport_code va 
 ON (a.IATA = va.iata)
    JOIN weather2 w
 ON (va.stationid = w.ID AND w.Year = f.Year AND w.Month = f.Month and w.Day=f.DayofMonth)
    WHERE f.DepDelay>15 and w.Sflag = '0'
    CASE 
           WHEN Sflag = 0 THEN '9'
           ELSE Sflag
    FROM weather
;

Can you help me to check whether have mistake or not? :)

Comment: The case at the end does not make sense